# Issues when camping during trek in Georgia?

Tags: georgia-country, camping, mountains, trekking

What should I consider when planning to sleep in tents during trekking in Georgia?

We plan to move for about 2 weeks to Georgia, about half that time in cities, half in the mountains. The tourist base is AFAIK quite weak, so we've thought about taking tents. So, what should we consider? Is it safe to camp in Georgia? Are there regions where it's fully safe and  regions which we should avoid? What places would you recommend going to spend beautiful days and safe nights on the mountains of that country?

Comment: From [`hitchwiki.org`](http://hitchwiki.org/en/Georgia_(country)#Sleeping): "Pitching a tent is a normal thing for the local people, forbidden only in city centres and near ruins."

Comment: @hippietrail: Maybe you can flesh this out as an answer quoting Hitchwiki / your own experience.

Comment: I actually did camp in the park in the centres of one small town where the friendly police came and told us it was OK and in one small city. Apart from that I only camped two other times in Georgia: once on a kind-of hidden beach and once in a field next to a not very well developed beach ... where I had to move my tent to make way for a state visit from the president!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer to my own question will not deal with all issues mentioned, but because there are no other answers I'd like to share my experiences.

I wasn't personally camping in Georgia, but I met people that were camping and I saw people camping.

Georgia still has an underdeveloped tourist base, most of the sleeping places are in hotels (big cities) and guesthouses/private rooms. But I saw a camping place advertised in Mestia (Svanetia) and I saw people camping outside a bar in Vardzia (so their backyard was a kind of camping place, you could say.

I met a few Israeli tourists that were trekking from Kazbegi to Tushetia and they said they'd slept most of their nights in tents and there were no security issues. But they camped only in places far from villages, when they were near some village, they've stayed there.

I also met one guy travelling from Uzbekistan to Georgia by hitchhiking and sleeping in a tent, and he said he had no problems or security issues, neither from people nor from wild animals or dogs.

But one thing you should always avoid is getting near flocks of sheep, because they are protected by very large and aggressive dogs, whose task is to protect the animals from everything including wolves and bears.